# How to setup smtp server without authentication in java

Tags: java, spring, smtp, jakarta-mail

Initially i was using 'smtp.gmail.com' as smtp server for sending mails using javamail api. But now i have to change smtp server and use our client smtp server.
The client smtp server let say is '143.12.12.1' and its without authentication.

So, can anybody tell me what configuration i need to do ?Do i need to ask my client for the sender email which is created in their domain(Domain mean smtp server).

Currently , i am using gmail id as sender id and smtp server is of client '143.12.12.1'.

I have used following smtp configuration in my code:-

smtp.config file configurations

```
#Email Configuration
host = 143.12.12.1
port = 25
isAuth = false
startTLS = true
startSSL= false
socketFactory = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
isFallback = false
isDebug = true
emailUser =abc@gmail.com
password = abc
```

#### ApplicationContext.xml configuration

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${host}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
        <property name="session" ref="mailSession"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSession" class="javax.mail.Session" factory-method="getInstance">
        <constructor-arg>
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${isAuth}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">${startTLS}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">${startSSL}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">${port}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">${socketFactory}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback">${isFallback}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.debug">${isDebug}</prop>
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="smtpAuthenticator" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="smtpAuthenticator" class="com.ericsson.obhs.util.SmtpAuthenticator">
        <constructor-arg value="${emailUser}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${password}" />
    </bean
```

>

Each time i am trying to send mail, i am getting following errror :-

***org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; message exception details (1) are:***

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all the socket factory and port settings, [you don't need them](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) and they're causing you to connect on the wrong port.  You might need to set `startTLS = false` depending on the requirements of your server.

You'll definitely want the "From" address to be an address known to your client mail server.